# Drools Absence of hitting a rule over a perios of time

Tags: java, spring-boot, streaming, drools, rules

I am new to Drools. I need to build an application with spring-boot & Drools(7.40.0.Final) where springboot application streams an external source that will continuously trigger data packets (tracking data related to movement of an entity) to my application. I need to use evaluate all these streaming data.

I am using a "geofence_rule.drl" file to keep the rules related to the geographic locations.

```
rule "Rule for Tag position in room 1"
when
    model : ComponentModel(positionValue <= 50)
then
    model.setRoomId(1);
end

rule "Rule for Tag position in room 2"
when
    model : ComponentModel(positionValue > 50)))
then
    model.setRoomId(2);
end
```

Model class is as below.

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class ComponentModel{

    private long tagId;
    private long roomId;
    private int positionValue;

}
```

I may get position related data of "n" number of tags say tag1, tag2 tag3 and so on. I **need to calculate if tag1 is absent from Room-1** (which means tag-1's data does not hit "Rule for Tag position in room 1") for Last 5 minutes. Is there any support in Drools for such calculation?

I have seen "not" keyword in drools documentation. But it just negating the condition of Rule. I need to check rule hiting nature for last few minutes, this time limit is configurable in application.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [*stream mode*](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#cep-modes-con_decision-engine) and [*negative patterns*](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#cep-negative-patterns_decision-engine). The links are to the official Drools documentation.

Stream mode is one of two event modes in Drools. The default is "cloud" mode, where you have all of the facts up front and it makes decisions automatically. The other mode, "stream" mode, is intended for processing temporal streams, which sounds a lot like your "pinging" application. In stream mode, Drools evaluates each fact as it comes in, and is aware of time -- namely when other facts were in.

Negative patterns in stream mode are the logical temporal extension of the `not` keyword. As you correctly pointed out, in cloud mode it simply negates a condition (eg. "there is no condition in working memory that matches this criteria.") In stream mode, however, you can update these patterns to take effect over a period of time.

The Drools documentation provides this example:

```
rule "Sound the alarm"
when
  $h: Heartbeat() from entry-point "MonitoringStream"
  not(Heartbeat(this != $h, this after[0s,10s] $h) from entry-point "MonitoringStream")
then
  // Sound the alarm.
end
```

The first line in the 'when' clause identifies an instance of a heartbeat (`$h`). The second identifies the situation when a heartbeat is *not* received within 10 seconds. If both conditions are true, the rule is executed -- in this case an alarm is triggered.

This is the same pattern you'd apply for your rule.

```
rule "Tag has not been in Room 1 for 5 minutes"
when
  // Tag with ID 1, present in Room 1 -- First instance
  $tag: ComponentModel( tagId == 1, roomId == 1 ) from entry-point "TrackingStream"

  // Trigger if this condition hasn't been met a second time within 5 minutes
  not( ComponentModel( 
    this != $tag, 
    tagId == 1,
    roomId == 1,
    this after[0s, 5m] $tag ) from entry-point "TrackingStream")
then
  // Do whatever it is you need to do for this condition
end
```

In this case, I'm leveraging the [`after`](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#cep-temporal-operators_decision-engine) temporal operator (link to Drools documentation.)

Basically this is how it works--

```
$tag: ComponentModel( tagId == 1, roomId == 1 ) from entry-point "TrackingStream"
```

The first condition identifies the scenario, in this case ID 1 is present in Room 1. It identifies the current *instance* of that situation we're tracking. Since this is a temporal stream, it's easy to think of it as "Tagged entity (1) has just entered Room 1."

```
not( ComponentModel( 
  this != $tag, 
  tagId == 1,
  roomId == 1,
  this after[0s, 5m] $tag 
) from entry-point "TrackingStream")
```

This is where the magic happens, and the syntax takes a bit getting used to. This second condition is waiting for the *next* temporal and then checking the conditions. The conditions checked are:

- TagID is 1,
- RoomId is 5

The temporal constraint (`this after[0s, 5m] $tag`) says to wait to check this condition. If a second ComponentModel is received within this time-frame after `$tag`, then the rule will not trip, and the scenario will repeat waiting for up to another 5 minutes. Since the time range `[0s, 5m]` starts checking immediately, we need to exclude `$tag` explicitly from the matching in the `not(...)` clause (`this != $tag`.)

---

To illustrate, this is how it might execute (simplified):

- 0m:00s - Event A ~ received (id = 1, room = 1). `$tag` = Event A. We begin checking incoming streams for the second condition.
- 0m:30s - Event B ~ received (id = 2, room = 1). ID mismatch; ignored.
- 0m:45s - Event C ~ received (id = 1, room = 1). Event A rule match 'cancelled'. Now checking for `$tag` = Event C.
- 5m:45s - No matching events received in 5 minute window, rule for Event C triggers right hand side.

Comment: Thanks @Roddy for the response. **negative patterns** are clear now. I would like to include one more checking too, which is the oposite condition of negative rule. 

In stream mode, Just like "Absence" checking, need to check as below,

rule "Tag is contineously present in Room 1 for 5 minutes"
when
     <...conditions...>
then
     <Do Alert>
end

How can we implement this kind of rules?

Comment: Simple, just change the roomId check in the rule. A tag is present in Room 1 for five minutes, if it is never present in any other room in that window. So just check that `roomId != 1` in the condition since that would indicate that Tag 1 is in a different room.

Comment: As per your first comment, At "0m:45s - Event C ~ received (id = 1, room = 1). EventA rule match 'cancelled' and checking for $tag = EventC". But when i try myself, EventA is not getting cancelled.  End result shows EventA and eventC as triggered.